# Convert a string to JSON Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, csvtojson

Hi I am getting a string like below when parsing a CSV file using csvtojson npm module .

`"{"baselineWifiStrength":"10Mbps","userWifiStrength":"3Mbps"}"`

Code to read from csv

```
const csvData = req.files.csvfile.data.toString('utf8');

 csvtojson().fromString(csvData).then(async (json) =>{

        const queriesNew = json.map(async (l) => {
        JSON.parse(l.structure); // crashes here 
})


})
```

How can I convert the above to a valid JSON Object . I am getting parse error If I do JSON.parse(). Is there a way to solve this ?

Basically I want to convert the `"{"baselineWifiStrength":"10Mbps","userWifiStrength":"3Mbps"}"` to valid JSON

Comment: Parses fine here

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry where ?

Comment: On my end, `JSON.parse('{"baselineWifiStrength":"10Mbps","userWifiStrength":"3Mbps"}')`

Comment: there is no "JSON Object" due to JSON is always a string. JSON strings can be parsed and converted to objects using `JSON.parse`

Comment: @CertainPerformance your works because you are trying out '{"baselineWifiStrength":"10Mbps","userWifiStrength":"3Mbps"}' but for me its "{"baselineWifiStrength":"10Mbps","userWifiStrength":"3Mbps"}"

Comment: So you have double quotes as the first and last character of the string?

Comment: @naveen Those two are exactly the same, just two different quotation marks, both of which can be used for strings. If your string does contain quotes at the very start and end, you may want to strip those.